# How to turn a nested for loop into a 2D list or array

Tags: python, arraylist, nested-for-loop

I want to ask a question about nested loops. I have a for-loop like this:

```
for x in range(1,5):
    for y in range(1,5):
        z =10
        print(x,y,z)
```

I have tried this:

```
list = []
for x in range(1,5):
    nested = []
    for y in range(1,5):
        z = 10
        nested.append(y)
    list.append(nested)
```

but this doesn't give me the output I want

I'd like to turn the nested for loop into a 2D list(array) to be like this:

Output:

```
[[1,1,10],[1,2,10],[1,3,10],[1,4,10],[2,1,10],[2,2,10].....,[4,4,10]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
z = 10
result = []
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(1,5):
        result.append([i,j,z])
```

or as a list comprehension

```
result = [[i,j,10] for i in range(1,5) for j in range(1,5)]
```

Comment: thanks! easy as that yet took me two hours lol

Answer (score 2):

Or with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

result = [[i, j, 10] for i, j in product(range(1, 5), range(1, 5))]
```

Comment: Even better, because it's faster

Answer (score 0):

Well, As Your Attempted Code:

```
list = []
for x in range(1,5):
    nested = []
    for y in range(1,5):
        z = 10
        nested.append(y)
    list.append(nested)
```

We can Simply Change it To Get Your PARTICLUAR Desired Out Put, Which Was This I guess?:

```
[[1, 1, 10], [1, 2, 10], [1, 3, 10], [1, 4, 10], [2, 1, 10], [2, 2, 10], [2, 3, 10], [2, 4, 10], [3, 1, 10], [3, 2, 10], [3, 3, 10], [3, 4, 10], [4, 1, 10], [4, 2, 10], [4, 3, 10], [4, 4, 10]]
```

For Getting This Out Put, Simply Change Your Code To This:

```
list1 = []
for x in range(1,5):
    for y in range(1,5):
        z =10
        nested = [x, y, z]
        list1.append(nested)
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 1, 10], [1, 2, 10], [1, 3, 10], [1, 4, 10], [2, 1, 10], [2, 2, 10], [2, 3, 10], [2, 4, 10], [3, 1, 10], [3, 2, 10], [3, 3, 10], [3, 4, 10], [4, 1, 10], [4, 2, 10], [4, 3, 10], [4, 4, 10]]
```

No Need To Import Any Module, Just Change Your Attempted Code a Bit! That's All! Simple and Easy! It Could Be Lengthy But It would Take a Little Time To Write!

Comment: Was I Bit Late? Well Anyways Hope Adam Or I Helped You! Best Of Luck For Coding!

Comment: "No Need To Import Any Module", right. But the code with `itertools` @funnydman posted is faster.

Comment: I said It Could Be Lengthy, But Its Simple For Elaine As I just Edited The Code Little Bit, funnydman is Good And Fast, The Difference Between His and Mine Code is That He Edited The Whole Code But I Didnt!

Comment: no I didn't mean that it's faster in code. It's faster in execution.

Comment: Oh Ok! My Code May Be Slow! No Problem To Me If It Helped The Question Owner!

Comment: I just mentioned it because it makes a difference if you use `itertools` or not. But yeah, your code works of course!

Comment: Thanks! Would Appreciate It!